Name of Cartoon Series where a girl knew all about flowers
there was a cartoon on the late 70's or early 80's about a girl that knew the names and meaning of all flowers, and had special powers based on what flower she was touching (this last part may not be true). 
I really do not remember more details, not even if it was a japanese animation or a western one.

Maybe: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hana_no_Ko_Runrun

I'm pretty sure that you are correct. Lunlun had the magical ability of changing her clothing using a magical pin that used flowers. The show was released in 1979 and has the honor of being the first anime in what was to become the magical girl genre. The show has been dubbed to several languages, so it's been seen by a lot of people. Here's a video that might help jog your memory.
